# Extract href of a specific anchor text in bash

Tags: html, regex, bash

I am trying to get the `href` of the most recent production release from [Exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/history.html) page.

```
curl -s  'http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/history.html' | grep -o -E "href=[\"'](.*)[\"'].*Version"
```

Actual output

```
href="Image-ExifTool-10.36.tar.gz">Version
```

I want this an as output

`Image-ExifTool-10.36.tar.gz`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `grep -P` you can use a lookahead and `\K` for match reset:

```
curl -s  'http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/history.html' |
grep -o -P "href=[\"']\K[^'\"]+(?=[\"']>Version)"

Image-ExifTool-10.36.tar.gz
```